# Proving an inequality with Multinomial theorem

Tags: inequality

I need to prove the following:

$$(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)^n \ge n^nX_1X_2\dots...X_n$$
when $n$ is an integer number equal or bigger than $1$ and all $X_i$ are positive.

I think it needs to be done by induction, and I could prove it for $n=1$ and $n=2$. For a general $n$, I think it needs to be done by the Multinomial theorem - but I can't prove it.

Comment: Think : why are all $x_i$ positive?

Comment: For a number of proofs of AM/GM, please [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Answer (score 0):

$Hint:$ Use $AM\geq GM$ on $X_i$